# Big O structure

Tags: javascript, big-o

Could anyone point me in the direction to where the Big O notation is in this coding I found? http://jsfiddle.net/neekit_rama/6qmoLbex/

```
<h1 id="title">Array operations with random functions & Big o notation Analysis</h1>

Enter an element to search(1-100):

<input type="text" id="myTextField1"/>

<input type="submit" id="byBtn" value="SearchArray" onclick="StoreArray()"/> <br>

Number of comparisions:<input type="text" id="myTextField2"/>
```

JavaScript:

```
function randomIntInc (low, high) {

    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (high - low + 1) + low);

}

function StoreArray(){

var numbers = new Array(100);

for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {

    numbers[i] = randomIntInc(1, 100)

}

var element = document.getElementById('myTextField1').value;

    var c=SearchArray(numbers,element);

   var t= document.getElementById('myTextField2');

   myTextField2.value=c;

}

function SearchArray(numbers, Element)

{



    var count=0;

   for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {

               count++;

       if(numbers[i]==Element)

       {

           alert('Element found!!.');

           return count;

       }

   }

    alert('Element not found!!.');

    return count;

}
```

Comment: Err, do you mean the big-O complexity of the algorithm: `O(n)`?

Comment: Looking for the Big-O for the loading of the array.

Comment: It's `O(n)`, where `n` is the length of the `numbers` array.

Comment: :-O   <--- this is a big O

Comment: thanks guys, cleared it up for me.

Answer (score 0):

The big-O complexity is `O(n)` where `n` is the number of elements in the `numbers` array.

`O(n)` complexity means that the algorithm scales proportionate to `n`. As `n` gets larger, the function will take a proportionately longer time to execute.

An easy way to figure out the complexity (for a simple loop-based algorithm like this) is by counting the number of comparisons:

```
for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    count++;
    if(numbers[i]==Element)
    ...
```

The comparison `numbers[i]==Element` is likely to be the most expensive operation in the loop, and it will be executed `numbers.length` times in the worst case.

In the best case, the `Element` will be the first item in the array, and so the comparison will only be executed 1 time, or `O(1)`. This happens because of the `return` statement that terminates the loop when a match is found.

In the worst case, the `Element` will be the last item in the array, or will not exist at all, and so the comparison will be executed `n` times.